# Where should I be mapping and filtering my data? In the react component, or the redux store

Tags: javascript, react-redux, array.prototype.map

My react component gets API data from multiple axios gets. I need to map and filter the data in various ways and am not sure about whether I should be doing so in the react Containers or the redux store. Further, even though my data is mounted, I get undefined results often, perhaps due to the async nature of the actions.

The app is a collection builder for banknote collectors. Users can browse notes from worldwide, view, add and edit notes in collections (CollectionBuilder) and wantlists (WantListBuilder - seen below).

The data are arrays of objects in three different arrays (regions, countries, banknotes) sent from my own API.

```
regions = [{ region_name: "Africa"}, { region_name: "Asia" }, { region_name: "Caribbean"}, etc.] length = 9

countries = [{ name: "Angola", reg_id: 1 }, { name: "Argentina", reg_id: 8 }, { name: "Armenia", reg_id: 5}, etc.] length = 209

banknotes = [ { ctry_id: 1, catalog_no: "151A", denomination: 5, currency: "Kwanzas", issue_date: "2012", img_url: "https://yadda-yadda-yadda" }, etc] length = 282
```

The key component is comprised of a select where choosing a region (e.g. Africa) populates a second select of countries from that region. When a country is select, the notes from that country are rendered.

I have been able to use map and filter to populate the selects and render all notes, but I cannot filter the notes to remove items already in a collection and want list in the collection and wantlist builders.

Also, I try to keep my state clean, so I have focused on manipulating the props in my components instead. Is this a sensible approach.

```
**Select.js component**

* IMPORTS *
    class Select extends Component {
          componentDidMount() {
            this.props.onGetRegions();
            this.props.onGetCountries();
          }

          regionHandler = event => {
            const selectedRegion = event.target.value;
            this.props.onRegionChange(selectedRegion);
          };

          countryHandler = event => {
            const selectedCountry = event.target.value;
            this.props.onCountryChange(selectedCountry);
          };

          render() {
            const { selectedRegion } = this.props;
            const { selectedCountry } = this.props;

        const region = this.props.regions.map(region => {
          return (
            <RegionOption
              key={region.id}
              id={region.id}
              region={region.region_name}
            />
          );
        });

        const filteredCountries = this.props.countries.filter(
          country => country.reg_id === parseInt(selectedRegion)
        );

        const renderedCountries = filteredCountries.map(country => {
          return (
            <CountryOption
              key={country.id}
              id={country.id}
              country={country.name}
            />
          );
        });

        let label;
        if (selectedRegion) {
          label = <SelectLabelDirective />;
        } else {
          label = <SelectLabel />;
        }

        return (
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col className={styles.Col}>
                <label>Select a Region</label>
                <hr />
                <select
                  className={styles.Select}
                  name="regions"
                  value={selectedRegion}
                  onChange={this.regionHandler}
                >
                  {region}
                </select>
              </Col>
              <Col className={styles.Col}>
                {label}
                <hr />
                <select
                  className={styles.Select}
                  name="countries"
                  value={selectedCountry}
                  onChange={this.countryHandler}
                >
                  {renderedCountries}
                </select>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return {
        regions: state.select.regions,
        countries: state.select.countries,
        selectedRegion: state.select.selectedRegion,
        selectedCountry: state.select.selectedCountry
      };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
        onGetRegions: () => dispatch(actions.getRegions()),
        onGetCountries: () => dispatch(actions.getCountries()),
        onRegionChange: selectedRegion =>
          dispatch(actions.regionSelected(selectedRegion)),
        onCountryChange: selectedCountry =>
          dispatch(actions.countrySelected(selectedCountry))
      };
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Select);

**WantListBuilder.js container**

    * IMPORTS *

    class WantListBuilder extends Component {
      state = {
        fetched: false
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onFetchBanknotes();
        this.props.onFetchWantlist();
      }

      render() {
        let builder = <Spinner />;
        if (this.props.banknotes) {
          // const mapWant = this.props.wantlist.map(listnote => listnote)
          // const filterNotes = this.props.banknotes.filter(banknote => banknote.banknote_id !== mapWant.note_id)
          // console.log(mapWant[0], filterNotes);
          builder = (
            <Container>
              <h1>WantListBuilder Builder</h1>
              <Select />
              <Banknotes
                banknotes={this.props.banknotes}
                region={this.props.selectedRegion}
                country={this.props.selectedCountry}
                wantlist={this.props.wantlist}
              />
            </Container>
          );
        }
        return <div>{builder}</div>;
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      console.log("WANTLIST", state);
      return {
        banknotes: state.note.banknotes,
        selectedRegion: state.select.selectedRegion,
        selectedCountry: state.select.selectedCountry,
        wantlist: state.wantlist.wantlist
      };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
        onFetchBanknotes: () => dispatch(actions.fetchBanknotes()),
        onFetchWantlist: () => dispatch(wantListActions.fetchWantlist())
      };
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps(WantListBuilder);

**wantListReducer.js (banknoteReducer.js is identical, but with banknote: [] in state)**

    import * as actionTypes from "../../actions/wantlistActions/wantlistActionTypes";

    const intitialState = {
      wantlist: [],
      fetching: false,
      fetched: false,
      error: false
    };

    const fetchWantlistStart = (state, action) => {
      return { ...state, fetching: true }
    };
    const fetchWantlistFail = (state, action) => {
      return {state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
    };
    const fetchWantlist = (state, action) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        fetched: true,
        wantlist: action.payload
      }
    };

    const reducer = (state = intitialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) { 
        case actionTypes.FETCH_WANTLIST_START:
          return fetchWantlistStart(state, action);
        case actionTypes.FETCH_WANTLIST_FAIL:
          return fetchWantlistFail(state, action);
        case actionTypes.FETCH_WANTLIST:
          return fetchWantlist(state, action);
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };

    export default reducer;
```

In the WantListBuilder, I want to send a filtered array to the Banknotes.js component (which renders a card with the notes image, country, denomination, etc.) The array will remove the notes that are already on the user's wantlist from the notes rendered on the select actions. I cannot seem to render the necessary array to send a props. Sorry for the overkill. It's my first question attempt.